# Maps/blueprints of the interior of the Temple Mount

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, geography

I am looking for resources that have maps and/or blueprints of the interior of the Temple Mount. For example, showing the various tunnel systems, stairs, gates, chambers, etc. I would even appreciate maps of a particular section of the Temple Mount region.

Because the Temple Mount site was modified so drastically over time, if you post a map as an answer, please provide context and a time.

Comment: What does this have to do with Judaism? How is it [on topic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site?

Comment: I recommend looking up Leen Ritmeyer and Conrad Shick's works for a start.

Comment: This is an interesting read - https://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-4977407,00.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider looking at the works of [Leen Ritmeyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leen_Ritmeyer) who is a leading expert on the subject matter. His book [*The Quest*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9652206288) is a good overview on the topic, and he created a detailed map of the Temple Mount [here](https://www.ritmeyer.com/2008/12/05/the-temple-mount-and-the-national-geographic/) that was featured in National Geographic (December 2008) - you can see it [here](https://www.ritmeyer.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/12/jerusalemngposter.jpg) in small on his site.

There exists a high-res map on the [mitzvah project website](https://themitzvahproject.org/building-the-third-temple/) created by the Temple Foundation dated 1983 [here](https://themitzvahproject.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/photo8.jpg).

An academic approach was undertaken by the Madain Project [here](https://madainproject.com/temple_mount) which features several drawings, pictures and depictions from throughout the ages.

The [Jewish Virtual Library](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/the-temple-mount) features a [blueprint](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/jsource/images/templemount2.gif) but does not provide a date.

There also exists famously, a series of ordinance survey maps that were done in the late 19th century by [Captain Charles W. Wilso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_William_Wilson) which can be accessed [here](https://www.bible.ca/archeology/bible-archeology-jerusalem-temple-mount-charles-wilson-charles-warren.htm).

As far as the tunnel system there is a website by Emek Shaveh, an Israeli NGO "working to defend cultural heritage rights and to protect ancient sites" that features a drawing made by Leen Ritmeyer [here](https://emekshaveh.org/en/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/underground31.png)

Comment: Wow thank you @bondonk for the bounty! Wishing you much hatzlocho in your studies!

Answer (score 1):

The Beit HaMikdash by Rabbi Zalman Menachem Koren is one book that might be of interest.

הכותל ממאיר בן - דב. מרדכי נאור. זאב ענר
Might also be of interest.